# Totally stuck on putting code into functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written code which loops 5 times for product and 5 times for product price. This saves the product and the price into separate arrays which then goes through a bubble sorting algorithm, sorting the price and corresponding products from high to low.

It then calculates the total discounting the fifth (cheapest) product as free.

We're required to put everything into functions but I don't know where to start, as well as use an if-statement which I think may be best placed in with the for-loop for a ""/non-entry by the user which returns to the product/price input until the 5 condition is met.

Then we're to display in a side by side the product and price but I don't know how to display this, as the arrays are separate.

This is what I have so far:

```
array = []
array2 = []
for index in range(5):
    User_Product = input("What is the name of the product you wish to buy?")
    array.append(User_Product)
    Product_Price = int(input("What is the price of the product?"))
    array2.append(Product_Price)

totalPrice = array2
swapped = True
while swapped == True:
    swapped = False
    for x in range(1, len(array2)):
        if array2[x] > array2[x - 1]:
            array2[x - 1], array2[x] = array2[x], array2[x - 1]
            array[x - 1], array[x] = array[x], array [x - 1]
            swapped = True
print(array2)
print(array)

totalPrice[4] = 0
print("The total for your order is £",sum(totalPrice), "the fifth product is free!")
```

Comment: I'd use a dictionary for the product and price.

Comment: For the listing of the corresponding product/price?

Comment: Yes. A dictionary is a way to map key value pairs. So your product would be the key, and the price could be the value. This would prevent you from having to maintain pointers to each.

Comment: Your explanation actually makes so much more sense using a key and value. As I’m using an array which is filled via user input I’m assuming you could use the [0], [1], etc positions from the array to assign the key and value?

Comment: You don't need the positions at all. You just go through the loop 5x, putting the product as the key and the price as the value directly in the dictionary. Then you iterate through the dictionary, keeping track of which product has the lowest price, remove the product with the lowest price. You could then have a few functions: 1. `getProductInfo` This gets the product info 2. `removeLowestPriceProduct` This removes lowest priced item 3. `returnCartTotal` This adds up the price of the remaining products

Comment: I've managed to put the User input for both product and price, bubblesort and display products with corresoponding price into seperate functions. Everything works perfectly and discounts exactly how it should.

The only thing I need to fix now is the User input for products and prices as if a blank entry is used it breaks the program so some sort of if statement I think is needed.

Comment: Is the bubble sort a requirement? If not, you can use the `sort` function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to have only one container, with dictionaries or tuples inside, but having two arrays can do.

Based on my advanced knowledge of commerce, I think you should have a condition that "if the price sum is more than XXX money, then the fifth item is free".
Which literally translates into :

```py
if sum(totalPrice) > XXX:
    totalPrice[4] = 0
    print("The total for your order is £",sum(totalPrice), "the fifth product is free!")
else:
    # keep the price for the fifth
    print("The total for your order is £",sum(totalPrice), " if you had purchased for more, the fifth would have been free!")
```

As for your function problem, I think it is part of your (I assume) assignment. Did you understand how functions work ?

I would expect something like `read_products_and_prices`, `sort_products_on_their_price`, `apply_reduction_if_applicable`, `tell_the_final_price`, ... each taking parameters and returning results.
But this website is not for doing all of your homework. Clarify what is the exact problem and we would gladly help :)

Comment: We’ve to use array’s to store the user input as it’s to use code which we have learned hence why I’ve got empty arrays filled via user input. 

Yes it’s for an assignment. I really don’t understand how to put code into functions; our lecturer is French speaking English so a lot is very hard to understand/grasp. 

I’ve managed to put the bubble sort into a function but I’m struggling to put the user input into a function and now figuring out how to put the arrays into a key/value pair based on position and bubble sort.

Comment: @DonVeritas I recommend you follow some tutorials online. I know those from RealPython are generally very good, although I don't know this one : [defining your own Python function](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/). And as a French myself I know how difficult it can be for French non-english-speaking persons to give lectures in English, so I sympathize with you. In a nutshell, functions are made to reuse some code, it acts like a magic box that you give something in (inputs) and returns you something else (output). Then there is the Python syntax ...